# How to grid a polyline points? Pathfinding.js library

Tags: javascript, arrays, path-finding

I have a shape like this:[image]

Is it possible to grid them using their points and store it in an array?

```
<polyline class="st8" points="2022.5,409.3 1996.1,409.3 1996.1,296.8 1970.4,296.8 1970.4,324.4 1920.2,324.4 1920.2,429.3 
    1667.7,429.3 1667.7,360.5 1631.4,360.5 1631.4,408.5 1445,408.5 1445,362.3 1357.4,362.3 1357.4,408.5 962.3,408.5 962.3,362.3 
    874.8,362.3 874.8,408.5 721.1,408.5 721.1,362.3 633.6,362.3 633.6,408.5 480,408.5 225.4,408.5 225.4,370 168.9,370 168.9,408.6 
    113.3,408.6 113.3,512.4 110,512.4 170.4,512.4 170.4,564.9 170.4,595.1 170.4,633.5 191.2,633.5 225.2,633.5 225.2,590.2 
    225.2,500.5 479.9,500.5 589,500.5 589,546.5 721.4,546.5 721.4,500.5 914.4,500.5 914.7,546.5 986.9,546.5 987,500.5 
    1398.2,500.5 1398.3,546.5 1470.6,546.5 1470.6,500.5 1660.6,500.5 1660.6,544.9 1723,544.9 1723,500.5 1919.1,500.5 1919.1,511.3 
    2022.5,511.3 2022.5,409.3   "/>
```

**Edit:** Is it possible to use [Pathfinding.js](https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js) to the grid and how will I set the setWalkableAt function in the library?

Comment: You could get the value of the `points` attribute of the element and split the resulting string at the spaces. P.S. a [`<polygon>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon) is intended for closed shapes.

Comment: [2022.5,409.3] so the result would look like this?

Comment: I was intending that you would extend the idea of splitting at spaces to splitting at commas, whereupon you have two strings which you can then call [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) on (if you need to).

Comment: Could you please give an example as how would you do it? I could not follow what you said. I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the mention of the SVG DOM in [How do I add coordinates to an SVG polyline?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25708292/1115360), I came up with...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var polyline= document.getElementById("myPolyline");
    var pts = [];
    for (var i=0; i < polyline.points.length; i++) {
        pts.push([polyline.points[i].x, polyline.points[i].y]);
    }

    console.log(pts);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="1920" height="340">
<polyline id="myPolyline" class="st8" points="2022.5,409.3 1996.1,409.3 1996.1,296.8 1970.4,296.8 1970.4,324.4 1920.2,324.4 1920.2,429.3 
    1667.7,429.3 1667.7,360.5 1631.4,360.5 1631.4,408.5 1445,408.5 1445,362.3 1357.4,362.3 1357.4,408.5 962.3,408.5 962.3,362.3 
    874.8,362.3 874.8,408.5 721.1,408.5 721.1,362.3 633.6,362.3 633.6,408.5 480,408.5 225.4,408.5 225.4,370 168.9,370 168.9,408.6 
    113.3,408.6 113.3,512.4 110,512.4 170.4,512.4 170.4,564.9 170.4,595.1 170.4,633.5 191.2,633.5 225.2,633.5 225.2,590.2 
    225.2,500.5 479.9,500.5 589,500.5 589,546.5 721.4,546.5 721.4,500.5 914.4,500.5 914.7,546.5 986.9,546.5 987,500.5 
    1398.2,500.5 1398.3,546.5 1470.6,546.5 1470.6,500.5 1660.6,500.5 1660.6,544.9 1723,544.9 1723,500.5 1919.1,500.5 1919.1,511.3 
    2022.5,511.3 2022.5,409.3   "/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I gave the polyline an `id` attribute to make it easy to get a reference to it with `document.getElementById()`.

Look in the console of your browser's developer tools to see the array of arrays.